# Retornar E-mail de amigos Facebook friend_list

Tags: facebook

Utilizando a [graph-API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) do Facebook eu consigo obter vários dados do usuário que está logado em meu sistema (a [lista completa](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5) pode ser vista na doc do Facebook). Porém, gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de obter os dados de meus amigos, para ser mais específico, o e-mail.

Sei que posso utilizar a [taggable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/taggable_friends/) para marcar amigos que não utilizam minha aplicação, e a [invitable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.0) para poder convidar amigos (caso utilize canvas). Porém, em nenhuma dessas formas eu consigo recuperar o e-mail do amigo?

Grandes empresas, como o [Yahoo](http://techcrunch.com/2010/03/04/yahoo-contacts-gets-facebook-connect/) conseguem realizar essa importação de emails. É possível realizar isso através da API do facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infelizmente o Facebook [restringiu algumas funcionalidades](http://g1.globo.com/tecnologia/blog/seguranca-digital/post/facebook-restringe-aplicativos-e-aumenta-privacidade-de-usuarios.html) a fim de mater a privacidade dos usuários. Com isso, não é possível obter o e-mail da forma desejada.

Grandes empresas possuem um "acordo de senhores" para obterem esses dados, o que é normal em qualquer grande API no mercado.